What is an Affine PDE?
Is $\begin{align}
\frac{\partial^4u}{\partial x^3 \partial y}\,&+x\,\frac{\partial^3u}{\partial y^3}+7=0
\end{align}$ a linear, affine or quasilinear PDE?
I understand what a linear and a quasilinear PDE is but I haven't come across what an affine PDE is anywhere.
I ruled out non-linear as none of the partial derivative terms are raised to an exponent.
I ruled out quasilinear as none of the coefficients involve a $u$.
I ruled out semi-linear as 7 is not a function of u.
Therefore I just concluded the answer must be Linear but the answer is actually Affine. I don't understand what this is and how to differentiate between linear and affine.

An affine function is a function of the form $x \mapsto T(x) + v$, so a linear transformation + a translation. The LHS is an affine function of $u$.

Never heard the term “affine PDE” before. The standard definitions are defined in terms of the differential operator. One can always write a PDE in terms of $u$ and its partial derivatives up to a finite order $k$, $$ L(x,u,\partial u,\dots,\partial^ku)=f(x),$$ where $L(x,0,\cdots,0)=0$. If $L$ is a linear function of $(u,\dots,\partial^ku)$, then the PDE is linear. If $f=0$, it is also homogeneous. If $L$ is a linear function of $\partial^ku$, then it is quasilinear. If not, it is fully nonlinear.
